# Where is the mic for the singers on TV?

Tags: live-music, performance, musicals

I happened to see a new show on the ITV (a TV channel in the UK), called All Star Musicals. The singers should be singing live since it is a competition and there are judges, and also there is a big band playing at the front of the stage. But I couldn't find any microphone attached/clipped to/on the singers. Can anyone tell me how exactly the sound is collected in this case?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are three possibilities:

- the singers have the mics on them but really well hidden. They are often put in wigs.
- they are using boom mics (possibly very directional)
- it's all pre-recorded. There's no reason the jury can't judge a pre-recorded song.

Comment: If all pre-recorded, it would be very disappointing. But I noticed the "orchestra" is working hard at the same time and the singers don't show any sign of lipping.

Comment: @Ethan Pre-recorded is the least likely of those possibilities. The mics are most probably cleverly hidden.

Comment: Thanks. Really have no idea how the mics are hidden since I've really watched very carefully every single contestant. No clue where they are.

Comment: @Ethan: The standard places to put a microphone for a musical theater performance are on the forehead hidden just inside the hairline with the cable running underneath the hair on the head into the collar and down the back to a transmitter pack suspended or taped in between the shoulder blades, or the microphone attached to the ear and the cable going a similar way. In both cases, you would use microphones, cables, and covers that match the performer's skin. In this particular case, it's a TV show as well, so you can control which side of the performer you are showing in which detail.

Answer (score 0):

I've just googled again. The microphones should be cleverly hidden somewhere, which is common on theatre stages or in theatrical productions.

[Attaching Microphones for Theatre Use](https://www.soundhire.co.uk/attaching-microphones-for-theatre-use/)

> The best position is to run the microphone cable up the back of the neck and through the hair, with the end of the microphone just sticking out of the hair line, either in the centre of the forehead or above one of the eyes, again with the microphone head just in front of the hair line.

[Also this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-L2iHjxGp4)